# Spin j representation decomposed as tensor product of 2j copies of fundermental representation $\mathrm{SU}(2)$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, representation-theory, lie-groups

It is a general fact that for every $j\in\mathbb{N}_{0}/2$ there is an irreducible representation $V_{j}$ of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ with dimension $2j+1$. In fact, up to equivalence this are all irreps of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. In some paper, they authors claimed that every module $V_{j}$ can be written as the tensor product of 2j copies of the fundermental representation $V_{1/2}$. However, I wasn't able to derive this.

My starting point would be the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition formula, i.e.
$$V_{j_{1}}\otimes V_{j_{2}}\cong V_{\vert j_{1}-j_{2}\vert}\oplus V_{\vert j_{1}-j_{2}\vert+1}\oplus\dots\oplus V_{j_{1}+j_{2}}$$

When I apply this for $j_{1}=j_{2}=1/2$, I find
$$V_{\frac{1}{2}}\otimes V_{\frac{1}{2}}\cong V_{0}\oplus V_{1}$$
which is different from $V_{1}$. If I go on with induction, we have that
$$V_{\frac{1}{2}}\otimes V_{\frac{1}{2}}\otimes V_{\frac{1}{2}}\cong V_{\frac{1}{2}}\otimes (V_{0}\oplus V_{1})=(V_{0}\otimes V_{\frac{1}{2}})\oplus (V_{1}\otimes V_{\frac{1}{2}})\cong V_{\frac{1}{2}}\oplus (V_{\frac{1}{2}}\oplus V_{\frac{3}{2}})$$
which is also far away from $V_{3/2}$.

Is there any error in my arguments?

Comment: "in some paper the authors..." If I might make a comment: if only for psychological reasons, I think one should try to give references that others can look up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement "every module $V_j$ can be written as the tensor product of $2j$ copies of the fundamental representation $V_{1/2}$" is false. What is true is that $V_{j}$ can be realized as a submodule in $V_{1/2}^{\otimes 2j}$, namely that of completely symmetric tensors in $2j$ indices taking values $1$ or $2$.